# ODBC Batch size

Tags: ssis

Currently using ODBC source to load 50 million records from Oracle source in the ssis package. The batch size is 1000 would increasing this reduce the load time.Currently taking 20 hrs. Appreciate any other suggestions to get the load time down
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It depends, but most probably, yes. `BatchSize` is used with `DefaultBufferSize` and `DefaultBufferMaxRows` to tune the data flow. The "blunt instrument" approach to tuning is to take the maximum size, in bytes, of a single row, use this number to divide your `DefaultBufferSize` by the max row size, and this is maximum number of rows that the buffer can hold. You then set your `BatchSize` and `DefaultBufferMaxRows` to this value.

In reality there are many more factors that go into tuning a data flow that aren't really in the scope of this question.